# HP Recovery not working after rebooting for updates?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update

I own a HP Pavilion DV6000 and I'm running Windows Vista on it. I updated Windows after update I rebooted the laptop. After that It was not at all booting. Even I tried to boot from recovery disk, it loads the Windows file and show light blue screen with cursor.

Tell me what can be done?

Comment: What does Safe Mode do?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot boot, even from CD, then the situation is pretty bad.

The most you can do is make sure that all connections are well-seated and that the BIOS settings look correct.

If you cannot do that, or it didn't help, then get help from a repair-shop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I can boot into Ubuntu. I did'nt find any connection problem nor bios setting problem.

Comment: If you are sure that you have the correct boot CD, is it possible that it is bad ? In any case, it will help to know where does this CD come from and how exactly it is labeled.

Answer (score 0):

Test you memory and hard drive,

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/How-to-test-RAM-and-HDD-Hard-Drive/td-p/301638